# Finitely generated left $A$-modules, over a division algebra $A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, modules, solution-verification, algebras

Let $A$ be a division algebra over $k$, and let $M$ be a finitely generated left $A$-module. Show that $A^n \cong M$ for some natural number $n$.

---

My attempts: Assume that $M$ is generated by a minimal set $\{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n\}$. We have an $A$-module homomorphism $\varphi: A^n \longrightarrow M$ ($(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n) \mapsto a_1x_1+ a_2x_2+ \cdots+ a_nx_n$). Why is this an $A$-module homomorphism? If one can show that it is homomorphism, then clearly it is surjective.

Let $(0, 0, \cdots, 0) \neq (a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n) \in \ker(\varphi)$, such that $a_1x_1+ a_2x_2+ \cdots+ a_nx_n=0$. Note that at least one of $a_i$'s are non-zero, without loose of generality suppose that $a_n\neq0$. Then we have $x_n=-a_n^{-1}a_1x_1- \cdots - a_n^{-1}a_{n-1}x_{n-1}$, so $\{x_2, \cdots, x_n\}$ is a generating set, which contradicts the minimality of the gererating set.

Is my proof correct? Is there any need for our algebra to be finitely generated? Are some of the assumptions extra?

Comment: You only need $A$ to be a division ring. The proof is exactly the same as the proof that a vector space over a field has a basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all good. Your $\varphi$ is an $A$-module homomorphism because for all $a$, $a_1,\cdots,a_n \in A$, \begin{align*}
\varphi(a \cdot (a_1,\cdots,a_n)) &=\varphi(aa_1,\cdots,aa_n) \\ &= aa_1x_1+ \cdots+ aa_nx_n \\ &=a(a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n) \\ &=a \varphi(a_1,\cdots,a_n) \end{align*}

Comment: And the inverse map is given as $a_1x_1+ a_2x_2+ \cdots+ a_nx_n \mapsto (a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)$, am i right? Also, by a similar statement, we are able to show that every left $A$-moule (not necessarily finitely generated) over a division algebra, is a **free** module, am I right?

Comment: Yes. But like for infinite dimensional vector spaces you need Zorn's lemma